# ECS EC2 network mode registration

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-ecs

I want deploy my containers to ECS on EC2 with Ansible.

```
- name: Create ECS task definition
  ecs_taskdefinition:
    state: present
    launch_type: EC2
    network_mode: bridge
    family: taskdef
    execution_role_arn: "{{ execution_role_arn }}"
    cpu: '{{ cpu }}'
    memory: '{{ memory }}'
    containers:
      - name: app
        essential: true
        image: "{{ image }}"
        portMappings:
          - containerPort: "{{ port }}"
            hostPort: "{{ port }}"
        logConfiguration:
          logDriver: awslogs
          options:
            awslogs-group: "{{ env }}-cw-app"
            awslogs-region: "{{ region }}"
            awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
  register: ecs_taskdefinition_output
  tags:
    - taskdef

- name: Create or update ECS Service
  ecs_service:
    state: present
    name: "service"
    cluster: "{{ env }}-app"
    task_definition: "app-taskdef:{{ ecs_taskdefinition_output.taskdefinition.revision }}"
    load_balancers:
      - targetGroupArn: "{{ loadbalancer.load_balancers[0].listeners[0].default_actions[0].target_group_arn }}"
        containerName: app
        containerPort: "{{ port }}"
    desired_count: "1"
    launch_type: EC2
    network_configuration:
      assign_public_ip: no
      security_groups: "{{ vpc_config.security_groups[0].group_id }}"
      subnets: ["{{ vpc_subnets.subnets[0].subnet_id }}", "{{ vpc_subnets.subnets[1].subnet_id }}"]
  tags:
    - service
```

I have ALB with target group `instance` type. Now I have:
- task definition with `bridge` network mode
- alb + tg `instance` type

If i do it manualy with WEB console, all work fine, but with ansible i have error

> Couldn't create service: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateService operation: Network Configuration is not valid for the given networkMode of this task definition.

How to do it with ansible?

Comment: From [`ecs_service` documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ecs_service_module.html)
> network_configuration [...] Only applicable for task definitions created with **awsvpc** `network_mode` [...]

Comment: What target group should use?

Comment: @Zeitounator if use awsvpc alb can't connect to ECS because container does not have ports